# Add preference activity in Android application with Java

Tags: java, android, apk, preferences

Developers have recently deprecated `android` library and all its classes, meaning `androidx` library is what is left. How do I now add the preferences activity and handle what is returned from a bundle?

```java
public class Preferences extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

    }
}
```

When I now add this in the `manifest.xml` I get `Preferences must extend android.app.Activity`

```xml
<activity
  android:name=".Preferences"
  android:label="@string/CONFIG_ACTIVITY"
  android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

</activity>
```

How I make a class call from the Main activity

```java
public void startConfigActivity(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Config.class);
  view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: There are lots of changes to the androidx library, but all tutorials from the web use Kotlin. Please any Java assistance?

Comment: Maybe this can be of any use? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#java and for initialization in manifest maybe this can help https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-android-jetpack-preferences-8bcb0b7bdd14